# Нужно ли коммитать package-lock.json, создаваемый npm?

Tags: node.js, git, npm

[NPM 5 поддерживает deterministic installs](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500), работающий за счет создания файла package-lock.json.

Нужно держать этот файл под сорс контролем?

Comment: Ета штука которую надо удалять если у тебя не устанавливается либа. Поетому держать в репе мало смысла.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Да, в этом его и смысл, чтоб у каждого кто пользуется репозиторием были одинаковые пакеты.

Comment: Эммм, а зачем? Что изменится если его добавлять в .gitignore

Comment: @BlackStar1991 у разрабочиков одного продукта могут быть разные версии библиотек/пакетов с различным функционалом + у разбработчика может стоять старая версия библиотеки под которой он писал код, а на продакшне накатится последняя версия с мажорными изменениями, как результат - нерабочий код.

Answer (score 6):

"Еще одна вещь, о которой стоит упомянуть: lock-файл точно описывает физическое дерево каталогов в директории node_modules. Преимущество этого заключается в том, что даже если разные разработчики используют разные версии NPM, они все равно должны иметь не только одни и те же версии зависимостей, но и то же самое дерево каталогов. Этим NPM 5 отличается от других пакетных менеджеров, таких как Yarn."

...

"lock-файл представляет собой моментальный слепок текущего дерева зависимостей и позволяет воспроизводить сборки между машинами разработчиков. 
**Поэтому рекомендуется добавить его в свою систему контроля версий**." ©

Источник: https://medium.com/devschacht/understanding-lock-files-in-npm-5-4bf615c6cd50

Answer (score 0):

`package-lock.json` фиксирует но не гарантирует установку тех же версий пакетов.

[чуть более подробно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/918655/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-package-lock-json/1186832#1186832)