# Для чего нужен package-lock.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, npm, package

Доброе время суток.
Я почитал документацию к NPM, почитал форумы, но всё равно до конца не совсем понимаю, смысловую нагрузку этого файла.

Вот то что описано на npm документации:

> Этот файл предназначен для фиксации в исходных хранилищах и
>   предназначен для различных целей:
>
> **1)** Описывает единственное представление дерева зависимостей, чтобы товарищи
>   по команде, разворачивая проект гарантированно
>   установил одинаковые зависимости.
>
> **2)** Предоставьте пользователям возможность «путешествовать во времени» к
>   предыдущим состояниям node_modules без фиксации самого каталога.
>
> **3)** Для облегчения большей видимости изменений в дереве с помощью читаемых
>   исходных текстов контроля.
>
> **4)** И оптимизировать процесс установки, позволяя npm пропускать
>   повторяющиеся установленные пакеты.

Вопрос сразу по 1 пункту, ибо у меня `package.json` и `package-lock.json` не в гит игноре! Они комитятся.
И как написано в той же документашке, когда мы делаем **`npm i`**, пакетный менеджер устанавливает зависимости, которые описаны в файле `package.json`.
И скачав очередную библиотеку мы идем внутрь неё и устанавливаем её зависимости (и так рекурсивно).
На данном этапе в `package-lock.json` просто выводится информация какие внутренние зависимости основных библиотек мы скачали.
Как оно помогает "гарантированно установил одинаковые зависимости" ?

И это всё полностью вытекает из 3 пункта.

Ну и согласен с 4 пунктом, по факту если в `node_modules` уже есть такой пакет (с той же версией и хешем), то его устанавливать не будут. НО, опять же эту инфу можно смотреть не по `package-lock.json`, а в зависимостях основного пакета, ибо почти у каждой либы есть внутренний `package.json`. Т.е нам не нужен промежуточный файл получается.

Верно ли я все понимаю? Пожалуйста, поправьте!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Помимо зависимостей, **package.json** используется так же для определения свойств проекта, описания, информации об авторе и лицензии, сценариев, в то время как **package-lock.json** используется исключительно для блокировки зависимостей от определенного номера версии.

Наличие package-lock.json в проекте не обязательно.
Так же для отключение автоматического создания этого файла ты можешь в **.npmrc** прописать **package-lock=false**

Answer (score 34):

Когда ты в package.json пишешь `jQuery: "1.3.*"` он за место звездочки подставляет самую большую цифру на данный момент, например 1.3.7, ты выгрузил проджект на гитхаб, какой то чел его через год скачал к себе на комп, нажал npm i а у него с интернета выкачалась 1.3.9 потому что разработчтки уже новую версию запилили, и у вас разные версии. вроде свиду одинаковые, но у друга баг есть, а у тебя бага нет. И решением служит добавление node_modules в гит, что крайне дикое решение. по этому, упрощенный слепок папки node_modules со всеми КОНКРЕТНЫМИ установленными там версиями, это и есть файлик package-lock.

Ты просто не node_modules в гит пихаешь а один этот файлик, и когда петя будет писать npm i у него точно такие же версии как и у тебя выкачаются из интернета.

Ваш кэп)

Плюс когда ты какие то операции через npm делаешь, если этот файлик есть, ноде не нужно бегать по node_modules и сканировать какие там версии установленны, она просто package-lock как базу данных использует

Comment: Вообще у меня есть идея) просто взять и такую моду создать "обьяснить по русски", без научной лабуды (которую чел и так очевидно гуглил но не понял), а просто взять и обьяснить че куда и зачем =) надеюсь прижевется

Comment: называется explain me like I'm five :)

Answer (score 3):

При повторной установке пакетов с зафиксированными версиями результирующий `node_modules` может отличаться, так как могут быть обновлены зависимости зависимостей. Чтобы добиться детерминированной установки в *npm* используется файл `package-lock.json`, в котором явно описываются все версии всех зависимостей.

При запуске команды `npm i` установщик получает список зависимостей проекта из `package.json` и во время их установки обновляет `package-lock.json`, записывая туда полное дерево зависимостей с необходимой метаинформацей.

Для установки пакетов из `package-lock.json` нужно использовать другую команду — `npm ci`. Эта команда устанавливает все зависимости, создавая идентичное дерево зависимостей на момент последнего выполнения `npm i`.

Кроме детерминированности, `npm ci` даёт очень хороший прирост скорости установки пакетов, поэтому чаще всего её используют в CI-системах.

Answer (score 1):

Фиксирование версий пакетов - это его предназначение.
Но всё же использование команды `npm install` не гарантирует установку тех же версий пакетов что были зафиксированы в `package-lock.json`.
В зависимости от того что написано в `package.json` перед версией пакета (я о символах `~` и `^`) пакеты всё же будут обновлены, а `package-lock.json` модифицирован самим `npm` в соответствии с установленными обновлениями.
Это поведение крайне не желательно во время автоматических сборок проекта и при установке пакетов (тоже автоматической во время `CI` сценариев) для прогона тестов.

Для этого существует команда `npm ci`.
[Согласно документации](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html), перед установкой пакетов при помощи этой команды, папка проекта `node_modules`, будет удаляться.